# In C# find the average of displayed value in a textbox that keeps changing its floating value for GPS nav program

Tags: c#, navigation, gps

Ok I have this program that utilizes GPS coordinates to find the direction of travel you need to get to the waypoint. I have the GPS coordinates display in 2 textboxs( Longtitude, Latitude).  The problem I am having is the fact the GPS coordinates( due to only being accurate down to 8 ft, and it constantly is fluxuating), is getting my heading to stay constant.  So I figured if I can somehow capture the average(5-10 readings) of the data being displayed in the textboxs, and take my heading from this then perhaps my heading will stay constant longer.  Unless someone else has an idea on how to do this.

for the code:

```
string[] locate=nav.Split(',');// array from a coordinate value recieve from listbox    
float nlat = (float)Math.Round((float.Parse(locate[0])),5);
float nlong = (float)Math.Round((float.Parse(locate[1])),5);
float gpslong = (float)Math.Round((float.Parse(longTxt.Text.ToString())),5);//value from GPS
float gpslat=(float)Math.Round((float.Parse(latTxt.Text.ToString())),5);//value from GPS
double pi = Math.PI;

float diffy = nlong- gpslong;
float diffx = nlat -gpslat;

double heading=(double)(Math.Atan2(diffy,diffx)*180/pi);

while (compassBearing > heading)//compassBearing is current heading, heading is needed
{
     Serialport.Write("l"); //turn left Motorcontroller is designed to keep going in a direction till another order is recieved
    return;
 }
while (compassBearing < heading)
{
     Serialport.Write("r");//turn right
     return;
 }
Serialport.Write("w");//drive forward
 if (nlong == gpslong  && nlat == gpslat)
 {
      Serialport.Write(" ");//stop
  }
```

With My code (which is navigating a robot) due to the gps coordinates not being constant, he will drive forward then instantly loose his bearing and turn left and right and then go again, if he goes again...  The digital compass that I am getting my current heading from fluctuates a little bit, but not as much as the GPS.  Anyway any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an reduce_accuracy variable to make it a little bit more inaccurate but stay constant for longer, which is quick and easy though i don't know how much better taking an average for every 5-10 reading would be... It depends on what you are trying to achieve

```
...
double reduce_accuracy = 1;

while (compassBearing > heading + reduce_accuracy)//compassBearing is current heading, heading is needed
{
     Serialport.Write("l"); //turn left Motorcontroller is designed to keep going in a direction till another order is recieved
    return;
 }
while (compassBearing < heading - reduce_accuracy)
{
     Serialport.Write("r");//turn right
     return;
}
...
```

Comment: I did that, and even went up to +5 and -5  still had same problem.  It was less though, but still same problem.

Comment: Well i am guessing that your target is too close and that is the problem since your gps accuracy is low for that kind of distance... You could either increase the reduce_accuracy value even more or try pointing it to a target further away

Comment: True, ordered a new Antenna, hoping that helps as well.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the GPS is only accurate within 8 feet that means your target is really roughly a circular area with a 16 foot diameter, right?  So, instead of creating a bearing on a point, you could be setting a bearing on the entire area.

My thinking is that when you get an updated robot location position you test to see if your current heading intersects with any point within 8 feet of your target.  If it does, don't change your roobot heading.  Even as your position indication flunctuates, since you're driving towards a larger area, your course corrections should be minimized.

Also, you may want to consider your distance to target. The farther away from your target, the less accurate you need to be.

Comment: Yes now the GPS digit wise would be more accurate than 8 feet, but that is why there is a fluctuation, and why I round it up to cover a bigger area.  less room for area, but your right, I could use the calculation from the distance, and have it not try to be so exact since the gps isnt anyway.

Comment: (dang phone)for the most part i am aggreeing with you, but that is why I rounded up the GPS.  I even rounded it up to 4 digits past the decimal.  It went straighter, but still same problem.